# MySQL- First row being skipped

Tags: php, mysql, row

I have a MySQL table which looks this -

[image]

When I try to print all the rows using the following code

```
<?php
include_once("connect.php");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM scores";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die("systemResult=Error");
$counter    = mysql_num_rows($query);

if($counter>0)
{
    print("systemResult=Success<br>");

    while($data=mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        $athleteName    = $data["athleteName"];
        print "&athleteName=" . $athleteName;
        print "<br>";
    }
}
else
{
    print("systemResult=Error");
}
?>
```

Exact copy of the code - http://pastebin.com/00WFdnrt

I get the following output

```
systemResult=Success
&athleteName=Guest-73
&athleteName=Guest-71
&athleteName=Guest-24
&athleteName=Guest-67
&athleteName=Guest-37
&athleteName=Guest-23
&athleteName=Guest-91
&athleteName=ankur
&athleteName=Guest-41
&athleteName=Guest-38
&athleteName=Guest-72
&athleteName=Guest-25
&athleteName=Guest-36
&athleteName=Guest-17
```

[Click here for the live version](http://mathlympics.cu.cc/php/getData.php)

As you can see the first row (id:1, atheleteName:ankur) is not being printed. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Note that the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated (see the [red box](http://php.net/mysql_query)).

Comment: Am i the only one  that gets a warning from a Virus Scanner when visiting his website? `
Web page: http://mathlympics.cu.cc/php/getData.php` --- 
`Access to the web page was blocked by ESET NOD32 Antivirus. The web page is on the list of websites with potentially dangerous content.`

Comment: Why timestamp for ankur is 0?

Comment: is this code you posted exactly in the page that you posted?

Comment: @AshReva Updated the image, previous one was a earlier version.

Comment: I can see that ankur is displayed in your output. Please look carefully

Comment: Can you retry to print output now and see ankur is displayed twice?

Comment: @AshReva Ok updated the image again, I forgot to refresh my table last time. The output is still same.

Comment: It is just because in your php you have not used any order to get your rows, try `SELECT * FROM scores ORDER BY id ASC`

Comment: @Akam yes pretty much - http://pastebin.com/00WFdnrt for exact copy

Comment: Is it possible for you to delete all records and just keep 2 records related to know and see what is output?

Comment: @AnkurSharma: Next time, please copy the exact code you use.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel Yes I will next time. This time I thought I would cut down unnecessary code like comments and such to keep it short and clean but that was stupid of me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code

```
           if($counter>0)
            {
                    print("systemResult=Success<br>");
                    $array = mysql_fetch_array($query);

                    while($data=mysql_fetch_array($query))
                    {
```

You have `mysql_fetch_array` *before* the `while` loop.

Just remove that line and you'll get the first record, too.

Comment: Marcel, do I see a different code than you? I don't see that line

Comment: @Sebas: in the Pastebin the OP provided: http://pastebin.com/00WFdnrt (see his comment).

Answer (score 2):

```
&athleteName=Guest-91
&athleteName=ankur
```

the row is listed, you need to use ORDER BY ID ASC in your query

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM scores ORDER BY ID ASC";
```

Update: according to posted code, mysql_fetch_array called twice:

```
        if($counter>0)
        {
                print("systemResult=Success<br>");

                $array = mysql_fetch_array($query);
                while($data=mysql_fetch_array($query))
                {
```

**Just remove the first one ( `$array = mysql_fetch_array($query);`)

Comment: @Akam updated the image. As you can probaly see I have two ankur rows, but only one is being outputted

Answer (score 1):

In this file you refer

@Akam yes pretty much - pastebin.com/00WFdnrt for exact copy – Ankur Sharma 2 mins ago

there is a line no. 9:

```
   $array = mysql_fetch_array($query);

   while($data=mysql_fetch_array($query))
```

which causes missing of the first record.

You did not write this in your question.